# How to turn off automatic applications updates from windows?

Tags: windows, automatic-update

Is there any way to turn off automatic updates of all applications in windows? Because of that my internet bill is going high. I turned off Windows updates, Chrome and Firefox auto updates and yet some other application is getting silent update. I don't know which application silently updating. Is there any software tool available to turn off auto updates of applications? Or is there any way to control auto updates of applications?

Answer (score 3):

If you go into your firewall settings you should be able to turn off anything connecting to the net from there if you authorized it.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-windows-firewall

http://www.techhive.com/article/209535/configure_windows_firewall_vista_7.html

Answer (score 3):

I have also turn them off, and turn them on once a month.

I have go to the `control panel | administrator tools | services`

and find the `Automatic Updates` and the `Background Intelligent Transfer Service` and turn them to manual from automatic.

Please note that if you left them to manual the Update Process is fail even if you start it by yourself. To make any update you must return them again to automatic !

The direct run for the services `%SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc /s`

Do not turn off services that you do not know what they do because then maybe the computer not start at all, and if you have this issue you need to boot with some helper os to open them back.